# passing header to html form

Tags: html, forms, http-headers

In Java I am able to specify http header using

```
 client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
 get.addHeader(key, value);
```

Now I need to create an html form, how do I pass the same data information?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, with pure HTML, cause the user's browser to send a particular header (other than `Post-Data` and so on).

If you need to send HTTP headers you'll have to use a Javascript `XMLHTTPRequest` or other dynamic device. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581383/adding-custom-http-headers-using-javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have a short example?

Comment: @tribal You mean like the ones at the link I provided?

Comment: The link provided has links which link to other links. So each reply seem very incomplete. I am pursuing the links, first learning about XHR. Not knowing how long it will take, I ask for a quick short and complete example. Thanks.