# HTTP requests and querystring vs headers?

Tags: http, rest

I'm trying to understand the difference between querystrings and headers. Where do you use each?

Query strings might be more useful in making URLs human readable I suppose, but other than that, wouldn't it be easier to just embed that in your own custom HTTP header (side question, but how this relate to cookies?)? What's the distinction between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer a similar question [Adding Custom HTTP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581383/adding-custom-http-headers-using-javascript)

Why would I prefer query string over http-header fields?

1. It is easy
2. I don't need any additional API
3. It is also recommended in
   [HTTP-RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-31) to "follow common-forms" when it comes to header
   fields.

Comment: The referenced question doesn't really answer the question "What's the distinction between the two?"