# How to add custom headers to request html page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have two ASP.NET solutions. Bot are running under different IIS websites. Lets say first one is called SOLUTION-A (this is a intranet portal) and the other one is SOLUTION-B (custom business process solution).

I want to add custom header to SOLUTION-A before i call SOLUTION-B via simple html link like

X-PERMS_GUID

X-CALLER_GUID

Then in SOLUTION-B i want to read those two custom header from the request.

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom HTTP headers using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581383/adding-custom-http-headers-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can add custom header like so:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-PERMS_GUID","1");
```

Read custom header:

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues = request.Headers.GetValues("X-PERMS_GUID");
var id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```